# Flutter shrinking image size to use them into ListView or GridView

Tags: flutter

Since reading images from phone storages returns the full resolution images and flutter doesn't automatically shrink images based on the rendered size, and we get lake memory after showing them into `ListView` or `GridView`, how can i resolve this problem?

```
class StorageMediaBloc {
  BehaviorSubject<List<StorageMediaList>> _storageMedia$;
  BehaviorSubject<List<MediaModel>> _imagesMedia$;
  BehaviorSubject<List<MediaModel>> _videosMedia$;

  BehaviorSubject<List<MediaModel>> get imagesMedia$ => _imagesMedia$;
  BehaviorSubject<List<MediaModel>> get videosMedia$ => _videosMedia$;

  StorageMediaBloc() {
    _initStreams();
    _initObservers();
  }

  Future<void> fetchVideos()async {
    try {
      final String videos = await StoragePath.videoPath;
      _videosMedia$.add((jsonDecode(videos) as List).map<MediaModel>((json) => MediaModel.fromJson(json as Map<String,dynamic>)).toList());
    } on PlatformException {
      _videosMedia$.add([]);
    }
  }
  Future<void> fetchImages() async {
    try {
      final String images = await StoragePath.imagesPath;
      _imagesMedia$.add((jsonDecode(images) as List).map<MediaModel>((json) => MediaModel.fromJson(json as Map<String,dynamic>)).toList());
    } on PlatformException {
      _imagesMedia$.add([]);
    }
  }

  void _initStreams() {
    _storageMedia$ = BehaviorSubject<List<StorageMediaList>>();
    _imagesMedia$ = BehaviorSubject<List<MediaModel>>();
    _videosMedia$ = BehaviorSubject<List<MediaModel>>();
  }

  void _initObservers() {
    _videosMedia$.listen((List<MediaModel> mediaList) {
    });
    _imagesMedia$.listen((List<MediaModel> mediaList) {
    });
  }

  void dispose() {
    _storageMedia$.close();
  }
}
```

build and show images

```
StreamBuilder<List<MediaModel>>(
    stream: _globalBloc.storageMediaBloc.imagesMedia$,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator( ),
        );
      }
      final List<MediaModel> _allImages = snapshot.data;
      changeValueNotifierValue(_allImages);

      final List<File> _imagesFiles = _allImages[0].files.map((e) => File('$e')).toList();
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 50.0,
            height: 5.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              color: Colors.black
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ClipRRect(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              child: DragSelectGridView(
                gridController: controller,
                scrollController: scrollController,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                cacheExtent: 1500,
                itemCount: _imagesFiles.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index, selected) {
                  return AspectRatio(
                           aspectRatio: 1,
                           child: Image.file(_media,fit: BoxFit.cover,))
                },
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_native_image](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_image) plugin to reduce the image size as per your container size.
Firstly check if size not as per your requirement using `ImageProperties`

```dart
ImageProperties properties = await FlutterNativeImage.getImageProperties(file.path);
```

Then compress the copied image to any private folder and use it and delete it later if you want.

```dart
File compressedFile = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(file.path, quality: 80, 
    targetWidth: 600, targetHeight: 300);
```